# load texture from obj file ?

Tags: c++, directx

in general DXSDK tutorial each vertex have only one uv coordinate , but in the obj file i have more than uv for each vertex why ? how i do to render the texture !?

how i can load this textures in c++

example

```
v -0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
v -0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
v 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
v -0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
v -0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
v 0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
vt 0.001992 0.001992
vt 0.998008 0.001992
vt 0.001992 0.998008
vt 0.998008 0.998008
vt 0.001992 0.001992
vt 0.998008 0.001992
vt 0.001992 0.998008
vt 0.998008 0.998008
vt 0.001992 0.001992
vt 0.998008 0.001992
vt 0.001992 0.998008
vt 0.998008 0.998008
vt 0.001992 0.001992
vt 0.998008 0.001992
vt 0.001992 0.998008
vt 0.998008 0.998008
vt 0.001992 0.001992
vt 0.998008 0.001992
vt 0.001992 0.998008
vt 0.998008 0.998008
vt 0.998008 0.998008
vt 0.001992 0.998008
vt 0.998008 0.001992
vt 0.001992 0.001992
vn 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
s 1
g pCube1
usemtl file1SG
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3
f 3/3/3 2/2/2 4/4/4
s 2
f 3/13/5 4/14/6 5/15/7
f 5/15/7 4/14/6 6/16/8
s 3
f 5/21/9 6/22/10 7/23/11
f 7/23/11 6/22/10 8/24/12
s 4
f 7/17/13 8/18/14 1/19/15
f 1/19/15 8/18/14 2/20/16
s 5
f 2/5/17 8/6/18 4/7/19
f 4/7/19 8/6/18 6/8/20
s 6
f 7/9/21 1/10/22 5/11/23
f 5/11/23 1/10/22 3/12/24
```

i have 8 vertices and more than 8 coordinate !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a different piece of texture for each face of the cube. while using indices list can make the box vertices using only 8 vertices, if each face has different texture coordinates, you need 24 texture coordinates. same for normals. Just load this a mesh using whatever class loads them in DirectX, and it will be fine.